# case multi-pattern with strings

Tags: shell-script

If a put "TITI" or "TETE" on V3 it doesn't work but "TOTO" will work. It's like it takes into account only the first possibility..."TOTO".

```
#! /bin/ksh -
V1=CRITICAL               
V2=HARD                   
V3=TITI                   

case "$V1:$V2:$V3" in     

CRITICAL:SOFT:TATA)       
    print "no"            
   ;;                    

CRITICAL:HARD:"TOTO"|"TITI"|"TETE")
    print "yes"           
    ;;                    
esac
```

Comment: What is `print`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging `print` is a `ksh`/`zsh` shell builtin used as a replacement for `echo` (and supports many  more options).

Comment: Please always mention what language you are writing in.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/ksh
…
CRITICAL:HARD:@("TOTO"|"TITI"|"TETE"))
```